# compiling maya (3d application ) with qt

Tags: qt, qt4, maya

including the maya ( 3d application ) classes in qt program gives lot of errors..... i have added all required include paths and libs...the same problem persists ....

this is pro file for my qt project

```
TARGET = FileCon
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp \
    dialog.cpp
HEADERS += dialog.h \
    ConvertFunction.h
FORMS += dialog.ui
LIBS += "C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2008/lib" \
        -lOpenMaya.lib  \
        -lFoundation.lib \
        -lOpenMayalib

INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2008/include"

DEFINES = _BOOL \
         WIN32 \
        REQUIRE_IOSTREAM
```

///////////////////////////////////////////

How is it possible to use maya classes with qt.

Comment: You might mention what errors you actually get...

Comment: I have one hypothesis based on very surprising (for me) LIBS syntax. But anyway if you refer to some error it is obligatory to give error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
LIBS += $$quote(-LC:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2008/lib) \
        -lOpenMaya \
        -lFoundation
```

[qmake LIBS variable](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs)

Comment: need some place to attach error and code. linux qt 64 bit - fine.  windows qt 32 bit - get error. difference : linux .pro - fontconfig windows .pro no fontconfig
-------
g++ -c -g -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -D_BOOL -DREQUIRE_IOSTREAM -DQT_DLL -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -I"..\..\..\Qt\2009.04\qt\include\QtCore" -I"..\..\..\Qt\2009.04\qt\include\QtGui" -I"..\..\..\Qt\2009.04\qt\include" -I"..\..\..\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2008\include" -I"..\..\..\Qt\2009.04\qt\include\ActiveQt" -I"debug" -I"." -I"..\..\..\Qt\2009.04\qt\mkspecs\win32-g++" -o debug\main.o main.cpp

Comment: in windows, qt when compiling does not recognise following in .pro file
LIBS += $$quote(-LC:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2008/lib) \
-lFoundation \
-lOpenMaya \
-lOpenMayalib \
-lOpenMayaRender

what change will make it successful

Comment: @knishua: you can edit your first message by adding this information in more well-organized form. What do you mean by "does not recognize"? Which error and on which step do you receive?

Comment: how do i edit the post to include code on a new line.
btw. By does not recognize, I mean, removing or adding the lines, the errors still occur. Where can i attach a file, so u can see.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using QtCreator with the included compiler on Windows, it expects ".a" style libraries, rather than Visual Studio ".lib" style libraries.

You still haven't given enough infromation about eaxctly what you are doing.  (How are you building, what compiler, etc.) or what is going wrong (exact error messages) to know for sure if that's the issue.  But, if my crystal ball is working well today, I'd recommend checking the library format.